# UWP - Get the text changes of a Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBox.TextChanged event

Tags: c#, c++, windows, uwp

trying to understand how to get the text changes from a UWP  Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBox control when its TextChanged event fires. I know I can store and compare the text before and after and if I have to I will do my own processing to determine what changed but the text can be very long and this can't be right or efficient. Every other platform (Android, iOS, Mac) tell you where the changes happened and what string was inserted. I'm pretty new to UWP so maybe I'm missing something?

```
void XAMLPage::Edit_TextChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextChangedEventArgs^ e)
```

Is there any way to determine what specifically changed about the text from this event?

Answer (score 2):

[`TextBox.BeforeTextChanging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.beforetextchanging) event is probably the best piece of API to track all the `TextBox.Text` changes.

The event is triggered before the `Text` property is updated, giving you access to the new and old `Text` values at the same time.

```
private void MyTextBox_BeforeTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxBeforeTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    var newText = args.NewText;
    var oldText = sender.Text;
    // TODO: process text change
}
```

Note that `TextBox` is not really designed or optimized to handle large volumes of text input; plus you end up with two string instances for before and after every text change anyway, making worrying about tracking text changes via some custom implementation that is not optimized for large text handling efficiency less of a concern.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is better than me keeping another copy of the text but I want to be sure there's no other way. You said that the TextBox is not really designed for large volumes of text, is there a control that is and provides that change info? I would think if not TextBox then RichEditBox, but I see the same lack of change info for its event args. What really confuses me is why they have this info for the TextBox under .NET System.Windows.Controls.TextBox but chose to remove it for UWP? The same TextChangedEventArgs there has a "Changes" property that gives that info :)

Comment: Talking about UWP `TextBox` control - sure there are other ways too. E.g. a `CharacterReceived` event would give you an inserted character in `CharacterReceivedRoutedEventArgs.Character` and the caret position after the insert in `TextBox.SelectionStart`, but `CharacterReceived` won't trigger on `delete` or any selection manipulations, plus it's a bit different for `backspace`, so you'd have to use more than one event to cover all text change scenarios.